# is it possible to put a cache the instance of XslCompiledTransform after Loading?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xslt, xslcompiledtransform

I need to save the result of the instance of XslCompiledTransform after the call of load method how can I do that?

Comment: How can you cache an integer?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a standard and efficient solution that works well both for ASP.NET and non-ASP.NET applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `System.Web.Caching` (it works OK outside of ASP.NET!):

**http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UsingTheASPNETCacheOutsideOfASPNET.aspx**

Comment: do you know if XslCompiledTransform is binary serialisable for my webgarden?

Comment: @Christophe `XslCompiledTransform` doesn't implement `ISerializable` so it can't be (binary) serialized.

Answer (score 1):

Save to Application scope variable:

```
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load("style.xsl");
Application["CompiledTransform"] = xslt;
```

use somewhere else later:

```
XslCompiledTransform xs = Application["CompiledTransform"] as XslCompiledTransform;
xs.Transform("input.xml", "output.xml");
```